# Why is BorderLayout not displaying properly with multiple layers?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, border-layout

I am setting up a UI for a blackjack helper program and while I know its not the most beautiful way to do things, it makes sense. 
The layering for what seems to be the upper layers is not working properly. Any suggestions? 
The left should have four layers, as should the middle and the right side should have two layers between the keypad and the enter buttons. Image is attached below.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

// main method, runs the program
class BlackjackHelper
{
    public static void main(String\[\] args)
    {
        Frame21 game = new Frame21();
        //pop window with rules of game
    }
}

// JFrame Construction
class Frame21 extends JFrame
{
    // create needed components of program
    JLabel questionDisplay = new JLabel("What is your first card?");
    JLabel actionDisplay = new JLabel("Enter your first card");
    JLabel dealerCardText = new JLabel("Dealer's Card:");
    JLabel dealerCardDisplay = new JLabel("N/A");
    JLabel handOneText = new JLabel("Hand One:");
    JLabel handOneDisplay = new JLabel("N/A");
    JLabel handTwoText = new JLabel("Hand Two:");
    JLabel handTwoDisplay = new JLabel("N/A");
    JLabel statsText = new JLabel("Win %:");
    JLabel statsDisplay = new JLabel("N/A");
    JButton aceButton = new JButton("A");
    JButton twoButton = new JButton("2");
    JButton threeButton = new JButton("3");
    JButton fourButton = new JButton("4");
    JButton fiveButton = new JButton("5");
    JButton sixButton = new JButton("6");
    JButton sevenButton = new JButton("7");
    JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
    JButton nineButton = new JButton("9");
    JButton tenButton = new JButton("10");
    JButton faceButton = new JButton("F");
    JButton clearButton = new JButton("C");
    JButton standButton = new JButton("Stand");
    JButton hitButton = new JButton("Hit");
    JButton doubleButton = new JButton("Double");
    JButton splitButton = new JButton("Split");
    JButton winButton = new JButton("Win");
    JButton loseButton = new JButton("Lose");
    JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset All");
    JButton enterButton = new JButton("Enter");

    public Frame21()
    {
        // JFrame - the main area of the program
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Blackjack Helper");

        // JPanel right - the rightside of the program
        JPanel rightSide = new JPanel();

        JPanel rightNorthSide = new JPanel();
        rightNorthSide.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));
        rightNorthSide.add(aceButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(twoButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(threeButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(fourButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(fiveButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(sixButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(sevenButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(eightButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(nineButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(tenButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(faceButton);
        rightNorthSide.add(clearButton);

        JPanel rightSouthSide = new JPanel();
        rightSouthSide.add(resetButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        rightSouthSide.add(enterButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        rightSide.add(rightNorthSide, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        rightSide.add(rightSouthSide, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(rightSide, BorderLayout.EAST);

        // JPanel Center - the center of the program
        JPanel center = new JPanel();

        JPanel centerNorth = new JPanel();
        centerNorth.add(questionDisplay, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        centerNorth.add(actionDisplay, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel centerSouth = new JPanel();

        JPanel centerSouthNorth = new JPanel();
        centerSouthNorth.add(dealerCardText, BorderLayout.WEST);
        centerSouthNorth.add(dealerCardDisplay, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel centerSouthSouth = new JPanel();

        JPanel centerSouthSouthWest = new JPanel();
        centerSouthSouthWest.add(handOneText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        centerSouthSouthWest.add(handOneDisplay, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel centerSouthSouthEast = new JPanel();
        centerSouthSouthEast.add(handTwoText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        centerSouthSouthEast.add(handTwoDisplay, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        centerSouthSouth.add(centerSouthSouthWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        centerSouthSouth.add(centerSouthSouthEast, BorderLayout.EAST);

        centerSouth.add(centerSouthNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        centerSouth.add(centerSouthSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        center.add(centerNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        center.add(centerSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // JPanel left - the center of the program
        JPanel left = new JPanel();

        JPanel leftNorth = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftNorthNorth = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftNorthSouth = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftSouth = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftSouthNorth = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftSouthSouth = new JPanel();

        leftNorthNorth.add(standButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        leftNorthNorth.add(hitButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        leftNorthSouth.add(doubleButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        leftNorthSouth.add(splitButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        leftNorth.add(leftNorthNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        leftNorth.add(leftNorthSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        leftSouthNorth.add(statsText, BorderLayout.WEST);
        leftSouthNorth.add(statsDisplay, BorderLayout.EAST);
        leftSouthSouth.add(winButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        leftSouthSouth.add(loseButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        leftSouth.add(leftSouthNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        leftSouth.add(leftSouthSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        left.add(leftNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        left.add(leftSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);

        frame.setSize(1600, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: _"The left should have four layers"_ sorry it is not clear what is the layout you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The layering for what seems to be the upper layers is not working properly. Any suggestions? The left should have four layers.

A BorderLayout does not "layer".

Only a single component can be added to each of the 5 areas of the BorderLayout.

So, yes, you can create a JPanel and add multiple components to that panel, and then add the panel to an area of the BorderLayout.

```
    JPanel rightSouthSide = new JPanel();
    rightSouthSide.add(resetButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    rightSouthSide.add(enterButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

However, the above code is incorrect. The default layout manager of a JPanel is the `FlowLayout`. So specifying BorderLayout constraints does nothing (and is very confusing).

If by "layers" you mean "rows", then you need to use a panel with a different layout manage. Maybe you can use a `BoxLayout` to add rows of panels.

Overall, your approach to creating panels with different components is valid, the problem is you also need to use the appropriate layout manager for each of your child panels.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information about how each of the layout managers work.

Comment: This comment had my solution. I was under the impression the that JPanel also had a default layout of BorderLayout, like JFrame does. Adding "new BorderLayout()" in the JPanel declaration solved my issue. Thank you for your assistance!